# Randomization check

Tags: r, chi-squared, contingency

I feel a little stupid for asking this question, but somehow I can't figure it out!

I am trying to see if participants are equally randomly assigned to two groups, so the contingency table looks like the below

```
Condition A    Condition B
30                40
```

The main data look like the one below

```
    Variable 1
P1   Condition A
P2   Condition B
P3   Condition A
P4   Condition A
P5   Condition B
P6   Condition A
.        .
.        .
.        .
```

What would be the best way/function to check (using R) that they were equally distributed to either of the conditions?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: `table(x$Variable1)`?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply - would there be a way to statistically check the difference?

Comment: If you are trying to check both the variable with `p = p1 p2 ...` then use `table(x$p, x$Variable1`

Comment: I'd think a chi-squared test would be appropriate (`chisq.test` in R). If you want more discussion on the statistical testing required to confirm/refute distributional claims, then it is a little more appropriate at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it seems to me that table(x$participantID, x$variable 1) does not give a statistical result

Comment: You are right, `table` does not give a statistical result. `chisq.test` does, and tends to operate on contingency tables such as the output of `table`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply & I will keep that in mind in the future!! Please correct me if I am wrong, but wouldn't a chi-square test require at least two cateogorical IVs? I still can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @r2evans after reading up some documents, I figured binom.test could be used - thanks for your help

Comment: That sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `chisq.test()`, which operates on a contingency table, not the raw vector of groups. The usage is simply like this:

```
> x = factor(sample(c('A', 'B'), 1000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.6, 0.4)))
> table(x)
x
  A   B
605 395
> chisq.test(table(x))

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  table(x)
X-squared = 44.1, df = 1, p-value = 3.12e-11
```